# Illegal string offset 'id' while using join query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am having some problem in Yii framework.I need to display join query result to my view page `pdtview`.But I get an error while displaying this resulting array.Here is my `controller page code`.

```
public function actionPdtview()
   {
        $model=new Products;
        $models=Products::model()->findAll();

        $rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('category.ctg,category.cid, products.*')
        ->from('category')
        ->join('products','category.cid = products.cid')
        ->queryRow();
//    print_r($rows);die;
            $this->render('pdtview',array('model'=>$rows));

       }
```

and view page code given below

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>sl.no</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Product</th>
</tr>


 <?php 
//    print_r($model);die;
      foreach($model as $row)
      {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ctg']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pdt']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
      ?>
</table>
```

I am trying to display query result using print_r() then correct output obtained.But in table format, i don't get the same result.Only get the error:`Illegal string offsets 'id'`.Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks to all in advance.

`print_r($model)` output (from the comments):

```
Array ( 
    [ctg] => Flowers 
    [cid] => 1 
    [id] => 1 
    [pdt] => lilly 
)
```

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Add your print_r result.

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($row)`?

Comment: I think column `id` is not in your table. You should use `cid` instead of `id` like this `$row['cid']`.

Comment: output of  print_r($model) is Array ( [ctg] => Flowers [cid] => 1 [id] => 1 [pdt] => lilly )

Comment: In your select query, you have not mentioned `id` column.

Comment: Maybe the `id` column exists in the table `products` extracted in the select with `products.*`

Comment: Are you sure that the `id` column exists in the $row? Try `foreach($model as $row) print_r($row);` to print all datas.

Comment: if `print_r($model) is Array ( [ctg] => Flowers [cid] => 1 [id] => 1 [pdt] => lilly ) ` returns this array. You can directly access `id` using` $model['id']`. No need of foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `queryAll` because `queryRow` only fetches the first row.

```
public function actionPdtview()
   {
        $model=new Products;
        $models=Products::model()->findAll();

        $rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('category.ctg,category.cid, products.*')
        ->from('category')
        ->join('products','category.cid = products.cid')
        ->queryAll();
        //  print_r($rows);die;
            $this->render('pdtview',array('model'=>$rows));

       }
```

This maybe might return an array of objects, which you can access so:

```
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->ctg; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->pdt; ?></td>
    </tr>
```